# How to use XStream in Mule?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, mule

I have written three classes implementing XStream.
It marshalls/unmarshalls the following XML.

```
<Message calledProgram="XXX" programName="YYY">
  <Fields>
    <Field name="SupplierName" value="ABC"/>
    <Field name="SupplierNo" value="123456"/>
    <Field name="SupplierCountry" value="AA"/>
    <Field name="TermsOfDelivery" value="5"/>
    <Field name="PaymentTerms" value="90"/>
    <Field name="Currency" value="GBP"/>
  </Fields>
</Message>
```

How do I use these classes in Mule? It is one Class that uses the other two so it is just one class to use.

I will be receiving an XML like above. I want to transform it to an Object.

It works in plain Java, but how do I use it in a flow. Getting all possible Exceptions from Mule.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: InstantiationException: xxx.com.GenericClass
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyB24Flow1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Unable to initialize XStream (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:208)
... 4 more


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyB24Flow1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Unable to initialize XStream
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:89)
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:109)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Unable to initialize XStream
at org.mule.module.xml.transformer.AbstractXStreamTransformer.initialise(AbstractXStreamTransformer.java:52)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:309)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:161)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:111)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:105)
at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:141)
at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:81)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 25 more
```

**Update:**

Though this is not my real code. But how do you mean OOTB? This doesn't work either. Have tried without the File-2-String as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.3.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml         http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
    <flow name="MyXStreamFlow1" doc:name="MyXStreamFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="E:\JavaDev\Test" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
    <logger message="WTF" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer doc:name="XML to Object"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Here's my main Java Class.

```
package test;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAsAttribute;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;

@XStreamAlias("Message")
public class GenericClass {

@XStreamAlias("calledProgram")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String calledProgram;

@XStreamAlias("programName")
@XStreamAsAttribute
private String programName;

@XStreamAlias("Fields")
private Fields flds = new Fields(
    new Field("nameValue1", "valueValue1"),
    new Field("nameValue2", "valueValue2"),
    new Field("nameValue3", "valueValue2"));

private static XStream xstream;

public GenericClass() {
    new GenericClass("calledProgram", "programName");
}

public GenericClass(String calledProgram, String programName) {
    xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xstream.processAnnotations(GenericClass.class);
    this.calledProgram = calledProgram;
    this.programName = programName;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GenericClass msg = new GenericClass();

    // Unmarshall
    FileInputStream file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(
                "E:\\JavaDev\\JRecordFiles\\Samples\\LevisTest.xml");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     msg = (GenericClass) xstream.fromXML(file);
     System.out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" + xstream.toXML(msg));
}
}
```

-

```
package test;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAsAttribute;


public class Field {

private String field;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private String name;

@XStreamAsAttribute
private String value;

/**
 * @param field
 */
public Field(String name, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}

/**
 * @return the field
 */
public String getField() {
    return field;
}

/**
 * @param field
 *            the field to set
 */
public void setField(String field) {
    this.field = field;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name
 *            the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the value
 */
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**
 * @param value
 *            the value to set
 */
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

}
```

-

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamImplicit;



public class Fields {

@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "Field")
private List<Field> fields;

public Fields(Field... field) {
    this.fields = Arrays.asList(field);
}

/**
 * @return the fields
 */
public List<Field> getFields() {
    return fields;
}

/**
 * @param fields
 *            the fields to set
 */
public void setFields(List<Field> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}

}
```

How do I use XStream in Mule?

Comment: Are you deploying these classes with your Mule application?

Comment: Hi David, I am trying to use my Class(es) in a Mule flow. But I don't know how to "use" them. I am a newbie. I am receiving an XML through JMS which I want to Tranform to an Object with XStream. BTW, just bought the MEAP for Mule in Action 2nd edition.

Comment: Are your classes on the classpath of the Mule project?

Comment: I don't have my code available at his time. The Classes is in my Mule-Project. How can I make sure they are on my classpath? Why isn't the above working OOTB as genjosanzo implied? When tranformed to an Object I actually want to Tranform it again to another Object. Move my Values from my new Object to an Object that will create Legacy Flat files.

Comment: It should work OOTB. Can you also share the JAva classes? That way we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: New update. How do I plugin my XStream Annotated Class into a Mle flow? Just added the main class.

Comment: Can't compile: the Fields and Field classes are missing.

Answer (score 3):

### The problem

The default **Object to XML** transformer only supports the **alias** annotation for classes:

```
<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML">
    <mulexml:alias name="myAlias" class="com.my.package.MyClass"/>
</mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer>
```

and ignores every other annotation. There is a already an [issue](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6364) since July 2012 on the official bug tracker, but it's unresolved until now.

### Solution: Custom XML to Object transformer

#### 1. Create the transformer

Create a custom transformer in Java which extends `AbstractMessageTransformer`:

```
public class ObjectToXml extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

  public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {

    XStream xstream = new XStream();

    // The payload should be the object to transform into XML
    Object object = message.getPayload();

    // Register all annotations in the XStream instance 
    xstream.processAnnotations(object.getClass());

    // Convert the object to XML and set it as payload
    message.setPayload(xstream.toXML(object));

    return message;
  }
}
```

#### 2. Use the custom transformer in your Mule flow

Add a **Java Transfromer** (not Java Component) to your flow:

```
<custom-transformer class="com.my.package.ObjectToXml" doc:name="Object to XML"/>
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you. I don't have the code to try it out since I have moved on to other projects. But seems reasonably.

/Ziggy

Comment: @ZiggyStardust maybe someone else will find this useful!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to configure the `xml-to-object-transformer` so it works OOTB with your XStream annotated classes. The only way I've been able to load the XML sample above and have your flow process it successfully is by using Spring to instantiate and configure XStream as shown below:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean name="xStream" class="com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream" />
    <spring:bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
        p:targetObject-ref="xStream"
        p:targetMethod="processAnnotations">
        <spring:property name="arguments">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>test.GenericClass</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

With this in place I use the following in lieu of the `xml-to-object-transformer`:

```
<expression-transformer
    expression="#[app.registry.xStream.fromXML(message.payload)]" />
```

I realize this is not super great so hopefully someone else will have a better solution.

Comment: Hi David. Not having any luck here. I am getting problems with the bean: Attribute targetObject-ref is not defined as a valid property of bean. Same for p:targetMethod. I do have the bean configurated. http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd Could you send the whole flow including xml-config. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of doing xml-to-object, how can I instead send an XML String to my XStream-class? can I call it as a POJO. Can you point me to a good webpage for an example of call ing a POJO? And then I want copy the Xstream-object values to another POJO. This POJO would then output a flatfile. This string would then be put on a JMS Queue.

Comment: I have `beans` bound to the standard Spring namespace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd` and `p` bound to the standard Spring P namespace `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"`.

Comment: The answer I gave you does exactly this: "send an XML String to my XStream-class" so I don't get your second comment. The only alternative I can see is, since the endgame is a flat file, to use an XSL-T to directly transform the source XML into TXT. No object deserialization/serialization needed in that case.

Comment: Hi David. I'm sorry but I keep getting problem with p-namespace. p:targetMethod="processAnnotations" gives "Attribute targetMethod is not defined as a valid property of bean" even though I have added `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"` . Can you show me your mule config file?

Comment: Where should I put the spring bean config? In my .mflow file? If so I'm just getting the error above. "Attribute targetMethod is not defined as a valid property of bean". I can't seems to get this into even running with a spring:bean as stated above.

Comment: Changed "spring:bean" to "bean" and that part worked. Will try out your solution shortly.

Comment: No, all this config goes in the mule-config.xml. It works as is, I've tested it several time with your flow.

Answer (score 0):

The [Xml to object](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/XmlObject+Transformers) transformer internally uses Xstream so it should work OOTB.

Please provide the flow configuration and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: See update. How can it just use OOTB? Above doesn't just work either.

Comment: New update. How do I plugin my XStream Annotated into a Mle flow?